# Running Selenium test from Jenkins on Linux

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing an issue where I am not able to execute the Selenium test on Linux box while executing from Jenkins. My Linux box is with GUI . When I am executing it manually after logging in to server with GUI and executing on terminal  it is executing fine. But when I am executing from Jenkins master and the linux box is a slave it is continuously spawning Chromedriver instances but not starting the browser. Has someone faced similar issue or have an idea for the same.

Thanks,
Amol

Comment: Do you have xvfb enabled when running in Jenkins?

Comment: Hi @smit9234 , I added xvfb and executed the test again.now also it spaws a lot of chrome driver but nothing else is happening . On the linux termial I can see a lot of process for chrome driver as well as for chrome and chrome-sandbox . Ultimately resulting in OOM error. I am also getting this in the log now . Highlighted is the new message which was not there before Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506092 (hash) on port 19327
Only local connections are allowed.
Oct 27 **org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS**